# Kinesis Analytics SQL query to narrow down the sensors that are not sending data

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-flink, aws-iot, amazon-kinesis-analytics

**Context:** We use Kinesis analytics to process our sensor data and find anomalies in the sensor data.

**Goal:** We need to identify the sensors that didn’t send the data for the past **`X`** minutes.

The following methods have been tried with Kinesis analytics SQL, but no luck:

- `Stagger Window` technique works for the **first 3 test cases**, but **doesn't work for test case 4**.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PUMP "STREAM_PUMP_ALERT_DOSCONNECTION" AS INSERT INTO "INTERMEDIATE_SQL_STREAM" SELECT STREAM "deviceID" as "device_key", count("deviceID") as "device_count", ROWTIME as "time" FROM  "INTERMEDIATE_SQL_STREAM_FOR_ROOM"
    WINDOWED BY STAGGER (
        PARTITION BY "deviceID", ROWTIME  RANGE INTERVAL '1' MINUTE);
```

- `Left join` and `group by` queries mentioned below doesn't work for all the test cases.

**Query 1:**

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PUMP "OUTPUT_STREAM_PUMP" AS
    INSERT INTO "INTERMEDIATE_SQL_STREAM_FOR_ROOM2"
        SELECT STREAM
        ROWTIME as "resultrowtime",
        Input2."device_key" as "device_key",
    FROM INTERMEDIATE_SQL_STREAM_FOR_ROOM
    OVER (RANGE INTERVAL '1' MINUTE PRECEDING) AS Input1
    LEFT JOIN INTERMEDIATE_SQL_STREAM_FOR_ROOM AS Input2
    ON
        Input1."device_key" = Input2."device_key"
        AND Input1.ROWTIME <> Input2.ROWTIME;
```

**Query 2:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PUMP "OUTPUT_STREAM_PUMP" AS
INSERT INTO "INTERMEDIATE_SQL_STREAM_FOR_ROOM2"
    SELECT STREAM
    ROWTIME as "resultrowtime",
    Input2."device_key" as "device_key"
FROM INTERMEDIATE_SQL_STREAM_FOR_ROOM
OVER (RANGE INTERVAL '1' MINUTE PRECEDING) AS Input1
LEFT JOIN INTERMEDIATE_SQL_STREAM_FOR_ROOM AS Input2
ON
    Input1."device_key" = Input2."device_key"
    AND TSDIFF(Input1, Input2) > 0;
```

**Query 3:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PUMP "OUTPUT_STREAM_PUMP" AS
INSERT INTO "INTERMEDIATE_SQL_STREAM_FOR_ROOM2"
    SELECT STREAM
    ROWTIME as "resultrowtime",
    Input2."device_key" as "device_key"
FROM INTERMEDIATE_SQL_STREAM_FOR_ROOM
OVER (RANGE INTERVAL '1' MINUTE PRECEDING) AS Input1
LEFT JOIN INTERMEDIATE_SQL_STREAM_FOR_ROOM AS Input2
ON
    Input1."device_key" = Input2."device_key"
    AND Input1.ROWTIME = Input2.ROWTIME;
CREATE OR REPLACE PUMP "OUTPUT_STREAM_PUMP2" AS
    INSERT INTO "DIS_CONN_DEST_SQL_STREAM_ALERT"
        SELECT STREAM "device_key", "count"
        FROM (
            SELECT STREAM
                "device_key",
                COUNT(*) as "count"
            FROM INTERMEDIATE_SQL_STREAM_FOR_ROOM2
            GROUP BY FLOOR(INTERMEDIATE_SQL_STREAM_FOR_ROOM2.ROWTIME TO MINUTE), "device_key"
            )
        WHERE "count" = 1;
```

Here are test cases for your reference:

**Test case 1:**

- Device 1 and Device 2 send data continuously to the Kinesis
  Analytics.
- After `X` minutes, Device 2 continues to send the data,
  but device 1 is not sending the data.

**Output for test case 1:**

We want the Kinesis Analytics to pop out Device 1, so that we know which device is not sending data.

**Test case 2 (Interval - 10 minutes)**

- Device 1 sends data at 09:00
- Device 2 sends data at 09:02
- Device 2 again sends the data at 09:11, but Device 1 doesn’t send any data.

**Output for test case 2:**

We want the Kinesis Analytics to pop out Device 1, so that we know which device is not sending data.

**Test case 3 (Interval - 10 minutes)**

- Device 1 and device 2 send data continuously to kinesis analytics.
- Both devices (1 & 2) don't send any data for the next 15 minutes.

**Output for test case 3:**

We want the Kinesis Analytics to pop out Device 1 & Device 2, so that we know which devices are not sending data.

**Test case 4: (Interval - 10 mins)**

- Device 1 sends data at 09:00
- Device 2 sends data at 09:02
- Device 1 again sends data at 09:04
- Device 2 again sends data at 09:06
- Then no data

**Output for test case 4:**

We want the analytics to pop out device 1 at 09:14 and pop out device 2 at 09:16. So that we can get the disconnected devices(i.e devices not sending data) after the exact interval.

**Note:** AWS Support directed us to simple queries that don't answer the question. Looks like they can help with the exact query only if we upgrade our support plan.

Comment: Are you working with event time or processing time? If event time, how is the watermarking configured?

Comment: Thank you @DavidAnderson for the question. For the staggering window, No time parameter is used. For the left join and groupBy, `ROWTIME` is used. This `ROWTIME` is added by kinesis analytics when a record is ingested. 

As per AWS docs, ROWTIME is an operator and system column that returns the time at which a particular row of a stream was created.

Comment: @LakshmanDiwaakar In the same boat, did you figure a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with all of the ways in which AWS has extended or modified Apache Flink, but open source Flink doesn't provide a simple way to detect that all sources have ceased to send data. One solution is to use something like a process function with processing-time timers to detect the absence of data.

The documentation has an example of something along these lines: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/operators/process_function/#example

Comment: Thank you @david for the answer, Will try it out as you said. Appreciate it.

Comment: @LakshmanDiwaakar Did this solution work for you? can you share further details of the solution please?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a pointer to an example in the documentation.